# Heroku application error H10

Tags: node.js, heroku

Getting this on my logs on a Heroku deploy attempt:

2017-01-05T13:22:25.579047+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fwc-node.herokuapp.com request_id=7c8a5b24-4af5-4c1b-a0d1-c373b4916459 fwd="2.102.204.147" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

2017-01-05T13:22:25.288450+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fwc-node.herokuapp.com request_id=47e66938-a57d-4d83-b1cf-220030adb90e fwd="2.102.204.147" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

2017-01-05T13:22:25.543923+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fwc-node.herokuapp.com request_id=10baa1a5-bcfc-496d-ae3a-f0dab4c01b36 fwd="2.102.204.147" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

this is my package .json
{
  "name": "application",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "private": "true",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "connect-mongo": "^1.3.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "csurf": "^1.9.0",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "express-handlebars": "^3.0.0",
    "express-session": "^1.14.2",
    "express-validator": "^3.1.1",
    "hbs": "~3.1.0",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.17",
    "mongoose": "^4.7.4",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "node": "0.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
    "session": "^0.1.0",
    "stripe": "^4.14.0"
  }
}

and Procfile
web: node ./bin/www

I tried Heroku restart and got this:
var bson = new BSON([BSON.Binary, BSON.Code, BSON.DBRef, BSON.Decimal128,
TypeError: BSON is not a constructor

Can't figure out why it won't deploy, thanks in advance!

Comment: Just wondering, I see you've fixed the issue. Could you tell me what you did? I'm having a similar problem...

Comment: Hi there, this was quite a while ago so I'm not sure. But I believe it was that I hadn't configured my Procfile correctly and that was what was causing the error. Hope this helps!